# Disjunction of timestamps

Tags: org-agenda, timestamped

I would like to be able to set the timestamp of some headers to an interval of time interpreted as 'or'.

For example, I would like to be able to assign a todo item at some point next month, but I don't want to specify a date yet nor I want the item to appear as todo on every day of next month (as would happen if I set the timestamp to an interval).
If I set an interval to be, say, Monday to Wednesday next week, I would like it to be interpreted as Monday or Tuesday or Wednesday.

I have tried to just have a different file for headers that are to be interpreted in this way, but it is not ideal.

Comment: What do you mean by "an interval of time interpreted as 'or'"? I don't understand that from your example. A "disjunction" of timestamps would be timestamp-A OR timestamp-B OR timestamp-C, wouldn't it? It wouldn't be an interval. Not clear to me what you want to do.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I meant that if I set an interval to be, say, Monday to Wednesday next week, I would like it to be interpreted as Monday or Tuesday or Wednesday.

Comment: Please put all such info in the question itself - it needs to stand on its own. Comments can be deleted at any time. Thx.